# Using command line args for completed hanoi program?

Tags: java, recursion, command-line, command-prompt, towers-of-hanoi

I just finished my towers of hanoi program. It works flawless, except now I need to somehow make it so my program can read command line arguments (and produce the same results as in my program). My program performs the exact same tasks as the output below, I just don't know how to make them look like the example below since I have never used command line arguments.

Frustrating for me, anyway, some example input should look like this :

`java hanoi 3 6` will solve the puzzle 4 times, for 3, 4, 5 and 6 disks, respectively.
`java hanoi 3 2` will solve the puzzle once, for 3 disks.
`java hanoi dog 6` will solve the puzzle 4 times, for 3, 4, 5 and 6 disks, respectively.

**How do I convert my program to use command line args like this?**

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class hanoi {
    static int moves = 0;
    static boolean displayMoves = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(" Enter the minimum number of Discs: ");
        Scanner minD = new Scanner(System.in);
      String height = minD.nextLine();
      System.out.println();
      char source = 'S', auxiliary = 'D', destination = 'A'; // 'Needles'

      System.out.print(" Enter the maximum number of Discs: ");
        Scanner maxD = new Scanner(System.in);
      int heightmx = maxD.nextInt();

//       if (heightmx.isEmpty()) {   //If not empty
//          // iMax = Integer.parseInt(heightmx);
//          int iMax = 3;
//          hanoi(iMax, source, destination, auxiliary);
//       }  
      System.out.println();


      int iHeight = 3; // Default is 3 
      if (!height.trim().isEmpty()) { // If not empty
      iHeight = Integer.parseInt(height); // Use that value

      if (iHeight > heightmx){
         hanoi(iHeight, source, destination, auxiliary);
      }

        System.out.print("Press 'v' or 'V' for a list of moves: ");
        Scanner show = new Scanner(System.in);
        String c = show.next();
        displayMoves = c.equalsIgnoreCase("v");   
      }

      for (int i = iHeight; i <= heightmx; i++) {     
           hanoi(i,source, destination, auxiliary);
         System.out.println(" Total Moves : " + moves);                    
      }
    }

    static void hanoi(int height,char source, char destination, char auxiliary) {
        if (height >= 1) {
            hanoi(height - 1, source, auxiliary, destination);
            if (displayMoves) {
                System.out.println(" Move disc from needle " + source + " to "
                        + destination);
            }
            moves++;
            hanoi(height - 1, auxiliary, destination, source);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Just noting, you have `char auxiliary = 'D', destination = 'A'`. Is this intended?  :) **EDIT:** Also, you are calling `.isEmpty()` on `heightmx` which is an `int` (not possible) and then passing it to `Integer.parseInt()` (not needed). **EDIT 2:** You don't need another scanner for each value read.

Answer (score 1):

You have the String[] args in

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

The first string in the array is your first line argument, second string is second line argument,...
Check size, parse to what you need.

Greetz chill.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

That magic method signature will contain any `String` params you pass from the command line.

so, for example:

```
java myProg a b c
```

Will have `a` `b` and `c` as part of the `args` array when I run my program. It's just a matter of processing the args passed in from the command line. They'll be there if you pass them.

Answer (score 0):

Command line arguments are passed to your main() method, so they are available in `args` as Strings. Just check how many there are (`args.length`) and if sufficient arguments were given, convert them to numbers the same way you do now. Otherwise, print an error or usage isntructions and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Command line arguments are read to `String[] args` which is passed to your main method as argument. Google would have found this faster.